# Ошибка при запуске локального сервера на Clojure в IntellijIDEA

Tags: clojure

Выводится ошибка по строке, которой даже нет. В [проекте](https://github.com/titov-andrei/joker/tree/ebc2bc2f73b4722d37f78a0ddee3eed6f34e9a71), сделанном по [видео с Joker 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_nlBeNIhZo).

По отдельности все функции компилируются без сообщений об ошибках. Но при запуске `run-server` из кода, на `localhost:8080` ничего не выводится и выдаётся ошибка в REPL:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException:
   No such namespace: ohs, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:33:3)
```

---

```
(ns joker.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [org.httpkit.server :as ohs]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]))

(defn index [req]
  {:body (str req)
   :status 200})

(def stop
  (ohs/run-server #'app {:port 8080})
  )

(comment
  ;; magic lib
  (require '[vinyasa.pull :as vp])
  (vp/pull 'http-kit)
  )


(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] "Hello World")
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (handler/site app-routes))
```

Comment: "при запуске `run-server`" каким образом? Из REPL?

Comment: @Кнопкатык - запускаю функцию из кода, но получается она копируется и выполняется в REPL

Comment: Ну, т. е. вы как-то обозначаете конкретную пару скобок (я так понимаю, которая внутри `stop`) и отправляете её в REPL, так? А попробуйте перед этим сделать то же самое с `ns`-формой наверху.

Comment: @Кнопкатык - запускал все функции по очереди и по порядку, начиная с пространства имён

Comment: Не надо действовать наугад. Если бы вы выполнили `ns`-форму, пространство имён `ohs` бы было.

Comment: @Кнопкатык - REPL и не ругается на `ohs` пока не доходит до некой несуществующей последней строки ... Пробелы и пустые строки в конце кода все удалил ...

Comment: При запуске в REPL происходит копирование кода из редактора в REPL. Информация о том, **откуда** этот код, не сохраняется. Используется порядковая нумерация строк в сессии REPL'а.

Comment: Вы там как, разобрались? Я могу написать в ответе, почему Clojure ругается на отсутствие `ohs`, но у меня подозрение, что у вас в другом проблема.

Comment: @Кнопкатык - пока не разобрался

Comment: Приведите пошагово, как воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: Было бы проще, если бы вы выложили весь проект на github, где его можно было бы посмотреть целиком на наличие ошибок.  Вероятно вы просто выполняете форму (в REPL же?) находясь в другом ns. проверьте что значение  переменной \*ns\* установлено в "joker.handler" и так же проверьте что joker.handler прописан в joker.core или что там у вас идет в качестве :main в project.clj

Comment: @Seryh - https://github.com/titov-andrei/joker

Comment: @Кнопкатык - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_nlBeNIhZo - делал по этому видео

Answer (score 2):

Надо понимать, что **это живое демо**, и код находится **в промежуточном состоянии**. В таком его обычно не коммитят, поскольку "как есть" он просто не запустится.

Загадка в макросе `comment`. Код внутри него не выполняется.

```
(defmacro comment
  "Ignores body, yields nil"
  {:added "1.0"}
  [& body])
```

А код специально завёрнут внутрь него, чтобы отдельные формы изнутри можно было выполнить явно, но выполнение формы целиком (eval file, например) их **не** выполняло.

Всё происходящее вызвано отсутствием библиотеки `http-kit`. И её действительно нет в вашем `project.clj`, поэтому и при старте REPL она отсутствует. Внутри `comment` размещены формы, которые затягивают эту библиотеку в текущую сессию. Саму форму `comment` выполнять бесполезно, она ничего не сделает (она разворачивается в `nil`). Надо выполнять формы внутри неё, по порядку, сверху вниз.

По-хорошему, надо в `project.clj` добавить `http-kit`. И выкинуть `comment` из кода вообще, оставив только в "файле-песочнице" для REPL.

Comment: "Всё происходящее вызвано отсутствием библиотеки http-kit" - так там же её "на лету цепляют" по видео, да и файл я не целиком запускаю, а как в видео, каждую функцию по порядку по ходу видео, и дошёл я только до 16 минуты - так почему по видео запускается веб-сервер, а у меня по тому же коду нет?

Comment: @titov_andrei в вопросе порядок действий не изложен. Но ошибка говорит именно об этом.

Comment: буду копать, спасибо за направление

Comment: @titov_andrei ну как? Разобрались, в чём беда?

Comment: понял, что матчасть ещё учить и учить...